# Allowing macros on an Access database on a network drive

Tags: ms-access, security

I made an access database on my desktop with several macros. I uploaded this to a network drive and when I open it, there is a message at the top that says:

"Microsoft has blocked macros from running because the source of the file is untrusted"

There is no option to allow them.

I have done some research on this and found two solutions which did not work for me. One was to look at the file properties and unblock the file. This option does not exist for me. The second was to go into the trust center settings and enable macros. They are enabled but it still will not let me use them.

Does anyone know another solution to this?

Comment: You need to add the folder as **trusted location** in trust center. Note that if there will be more users than just you, every user should have their local frontend with a common backend.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Feel like I should have thought of that. It will just be one user, but it has to be on the network.